# Python matrix index out of range

Tags: python, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix in python full of `' '` and `'#'`, i want to check if a position in the matrix has either `'#'` or `' '` surrounding him. Here is an example:

```
if matrix[i-1][j] == ' ':
   do something
if matrix[i][j-1] == '#':
   do something
```

But this will need a lot of ifs because i need to test if `i != 0` or `j != 0` otherwise it will check a position that doesn't even exist.
There is an easy way to do this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you just let your index run from (1, imax) rather than (0,imax) for i and j to avoid the edges.

If you are also interested in the things that surround your elements  indeces  in all directions, why not add up all neighbors like so (first change your matrix to 0s and 1s, matrix is named aa):

```
import numpy as np
num_neighbors=np.zeros_like(aa)
for i in range(1,imax-1):
    for j in range(1,jmax-1):
        num_neighbors[i,j]= np.sum(aa[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]) - aa[i,j]  
        # you need to subtract the center , it's not a neighbor to self
```

to sum up the values of all neighbors. In your case 8 would mean surrounded by 1s (#s) and 0 being surrounded by 0s (' 's).